# Date Range Picker in Future Dates or Past Dates

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I have a form in which i have two dynamic text boxes for Selecting from Date and To Date.Here I have Some Restrictions like User Should Select Dates Between

1)Past Dates Only
2)Future Dates Only
3)Current Date and Past Dates
4)Current Date and Future Dates Only
5)All the Dates

Is there any way to do with jQuery Date range Picker. or any other plug in available.

Answer (score 2):

If you use jQuery DatePicker ([from jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)), you must use the parameters provided by the API.

### Restricting dates for 1 datepicker

1. Set `maxDate` like this `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ maxDate: '-1d' });`, see demo here: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max and API doc here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate
2. Same for `minDate` and `'-1d'` value for future dates only restriction
3. Same using `maxDate` with `0` value
4. Same using `minDate` with `0` value
5. Do not set `minDate` and `maxDate`

See jsfiddle sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/dv8tf7oo/

In addition, those restrictions can also be added at runtime, not only during init.

### Basic From / To fields

See demo in jQuery UI demos: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

```
$(function() {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        onClose: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        onClose: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have done same thing for Date Picker with Single Text Box.But I am looking for "Date Range Picker" for 2 Text Boxes "From" and "To" Dates

Comment: If you are talking about `from` / `to` fields, I suppose the rule is that the `from` value must be before the `to` value. What is the exact rule (unclear in your question) for each field? Is the `from` value also before today for example?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Datepicker has minDate and maxDate properties that can be set to a given date or calculated based on the current date. You can use one or both of these to achieve your requirement.

See http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

For example, I use the following to restrict dates to between Jan 28 2014 and today

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                minDate: new Date(2014, 1-1, 28),
                maxDate: "+0D",
                dateFormat: "dd-MM-yy"
            });
```